# RPC for a PHP server and Ruby client?

Tags: php, ruby, rpc, middleware

I have a ruby web front end, and a php backend that i am developing. I am looking for some client server RPC implimentation that will work in ruby and PHP. 
I have tried msgpack to make RPC calls, but it doesent work, and i cant seem to get any support on it.

Can anyone recommend a simple RPC implementation that works in this instance?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ruby web front end", since Ruby is a server-side language. Can you put more details in how you're using Ruby in this system?

Answer (score 1):

You've asked specifically for RPC so I will provide you with an answer to that; however, I will follow-up with a recommendation.

1. [DNode for PHP](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php)
2. [DNode for Ruby](https://github.com/substack/dnode-ruby)

If you are not specifically tied to using RPC messaging, you might think about providing an JSON HTTP Web Service via PHP and consume that service via Ruby:

1. [FRAPI](http://getfrapi.com/) (simple PHP web service development)
2. [Ruby HTTP clients](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/ruby-http-performance-shootout-redux/) (pick one)